# Ice melting equation units don't match?

Tags: units, ice

I am working on a model to simulate algal growth in Antarctica, and want to incorporate surface ice melting.
I found this equation for melting:
$$ \frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{-kAT}{\rho L_f}$$
where $V$ is the melted volume in cubic meters, $k$ is thermal conductivity in Watt per degree Kelvin per meter,  $A$ is the melting area in square meters, $T$ is the temperature difference between the two surfaces in degrees kKelvin, $\rho$ is the density of the ice in kilograms per cubic meter and $L_f$ is the heat of fusion in Joule per kilogram.

The problem is: if I add all the units up, I get $m^4s^{-1}$ in stead of the  $m^3s^{-1}$ that I was expecting. 
Is there something wrong in the formula, or is the unit of the melted water realy $m^4s^{-1}$?

I know it's a simplified formula, but I don't want it to be too complicated. All i need is a rough water input from the ice into the ocean.

Edit:
The formula comes from this article. http://home2.fvcc.edu/~dhicketh/DiffEqns/spring2014projects/AudreyJones/Icecube.pdf
I have changed it, because I am using a 2D surface rather than a 3D cube, which might be where the problem comes from.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind your equation? Where did you get if from?

Comment: Ok, so in the article you are citing something is not right in the first equation of section 2.4: The dimension of the heat transfer $Q'$, which is supposed to have reasonable SI units of $\frac{\text{J}}{\text{s}}$, does not match the dimension of the expression $-kAT$, which has units of $\frac{\text{J}}{\text{s}}\text{m}$. Unfortunately, "After much research and consultation with experts the following general melting equation was developed." does not tell us how the author arrived at that equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@WojciechMorawiec is correct. The $k$ in the referenced article is not thermal conductivity.  What would thermal conductivity have to do with the transfer of energy *into* of the object?

$k$ in that formula is the [heat transfer coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_transfer_coefficient) which has units of W/m${}^2$/ K